# Get string between two special characters

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, awk

How do I `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, `tr` or whatever in a `bash script` to get the first occurrence per line of the characters between

```
'      and      .
```

from this file. (The character is a single quote and a period). This is really hard, I love that you're even trying.

So that the command yields:

Ideal output:

```
orinak
pchovi
orinak

xpt

moon
```

on the following file:

```
class GI_DnConstants {
        const BO_DOMAIN_NAME = 'orinak.backoffice.domain.com';
        const EX_DOMAIN_NAME = 'pchovi.extranet.domain.com';
        const WS_DOMAIN_NAME = 'orinak.www.domain.com';
        const PT_DOMAIN_NAME = '.partner.domain.com';
        const PTS_DOMAIN_NAME = 'xpt.partners.domain.com';
        const WS_SECURE_DOMAIN_NAME = '.secure.domain.com';
        const IMG_DOMAIN_NAME = 'moon.images.domain.com';
}
```

Comment: do you need the empty lines as well?

Comment: Yes, because it would show me that misconfiguration has happened. It works now with Taoufix's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the empty lines in output are not required, this grep with "look-around" will give what you want:

```
grep -Po "(?<=')[^.']*(?=\.)" file
```

just saw you tagged the question with **awk**

then try this awk **with** those empty lines in output:

```
awk -F"['.]" 'NF>2{print $2}' file
```

(the awk one-liner works for your input in example)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -n "s/.*'\([^\.]*\)\..*/\1/p" input_file.txt
```

Run:

```
$ sed -n "s/.*'\([^\.]*\)\..*/\1/p"  input_file.txt
orinak
pchovi
orinak

xpt

moon


$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
```

Comment: I don't know which version of sed you are using, but that command gives the exact result you are asking for, see update.

Comment: This is great, it worked!

My only question is, how can I now throw each of those lines into an array that I can traverse with a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
egrep -o "'[^\.,;]+" file | cut -c2-
```

Note: This don't print the empty lines.